# Jquery scroll horizontally and stop on every 3rd child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent `<div>` which has a 20 children `<div>` elements.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">content A</div>
<div class="child">content B</div>
<div class="child">content C</div>
<div class="child">content A</div>
<div class="child">content B</div>
<div class="child">content C</div>
<div class="child">content A</div>
<div class="child">content B</div>
<div class="child">content C</div>
<div class="child">content A</div>
<div class="child">content B</div>
<div class="child">content C</div>
</div>
```

I use the following Jquery

```
$(parent).on('scroll', function(event){
    //my code here
});
```

Here's my "next" button code.  As you can see, I can give the "scrollAmount" any number for the amount of scroll, but I want to stop the scroll when it reach the 3rd child element.

```
 $('.control--next').click(function(){
        var currScroll = $parent[0].scrollLeft;
        $parent.animate({scrollLeft:currScroll + scrollAmount}, 300);
    });
```

What I want, is when I click the "next" button, it will scroll horizontally and stop when it reached the 3rd child `<div>` element.  If I click the "next" button again, it will count from the current position another 3rd `<div>` until it reached the end.

Comment: The code you've shown will run when the user initiates the scrolling using a scrollbar, keyboard, mouse, or other input device. It has nothing to do with any kind of button. Please show a [mcve] demonstrating this `<div>` with children, any CSS styles you may have, and attempt you may have made to solve the issue yourself. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide that as a runnable code snippet here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wbndtzqu/2/

Note: The fiddles may behave a little weird due to how an embedded iframe is scrolling the page.

Here's the Javascript (assumes you have a next button with an id of "next"):

```
var nextDivPosition = 2 //Lists start at 0

document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".parent > div")
  if (nextDivPosition > elems.length-1) {nextDivPosition = 2}
  elems[nextDivPosition].scrollIntoView()
  nextDivPosition += 3
})
```

If you want to customize the scrolling a bit more, you can use window.scrollTo and elem.offestTop.

In the future, please give a more complete example. The one you provided was missing the next button, causing people to have to write their own code, quite likely different from yours, to get to where you already were.

Comment: Thanks mate, your answer help me to re-think my approach to the solution.